# resnet with show_and_tell instead of inception_v3

Tags: tensorflow

I have a resnet model trained in caffe. I want to try that with show_and_tell instead of inception_v3 image model.

1. What is the best way to convert the model form caffe to tensorflow
   model ?
2. How would I go about switching the inception model to resnet
   ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the "best" way, but there are some tools that seem to address this, like https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow